# How do I remove the percentage complete label from a Kendo Upload control?

Tags: kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui-mvc, kendo-upload

We are upgrading our old Telerik Upload control to Kendo Upload.
One additional functionality provided in the new control is percentage completion number.
We have decided that the progress bar is a sufficient indicator for the status bar.
Hence we plan to remove the percentage number that is actually displayed(right corner in the screenshot). How can it be removed?[image]

```
function onProgress(ev) {
var progress = ev.percentComplete;
}
```

the above property gives the number. I am not sure how do I disable it entirely!
fyi - Without even having onProgress function, the percentage is gettign dispalyed by default

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try hiding this by overriding the style of the `<span>` that contains the progress percentage using:

```
.k-upload-pct
{
    visibility:hidden;
    display:none;
}
```

Comment: It was difficult to identify this css class initially, although i did find it after some trial n error, display none worked fine